# Regarding boto and aws. While uploading to s3 as a multipart file I am not able to get the result for get_all_multipart_uploads

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a system where in we are performing upload of videos to aws by multi part upload. I have put this process as a work flow manager task. When the process completes I will update my database with the status of the payload as complete.

If the payload is not in completed status even after 24 hours I should delete the associated parts of the multipart upload from s3.

Now what all I have.
1. I have the video details(name)
2. I have the bucket in which I will be uploading the video.

When I perform the command bucket.get_all_multipart_uploads() I am not getting the asset which I have uploaded to the system, ie I dont find the name of the video which I had put on S3. I am pretty new to this. Can any one help me with proper documents and how to identify the uploads which hang on s3.

Comment: S3 can automatically clean up incomplete multipart uploads for you, [as of early 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-lifecycle-management-update-support-for-multipart-uploads-and-delete-markers/).  From your question, it is unclear what scenario you are trying to test.  If a multipart upload *succeeds*, it shouldn't be in the response.  Are you getting an unexpectedly empty response, or an incomplete response?  What's the exact nature of the problem?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you for the response. My scenario is something like this. Say I am uploading a file of 5 Gb and due to some network issues the upload process hangs and there is no response for my work flow task. Eventually time out happens. In that case will the file get cleaned up automatically or should we try to get the video uploaded by using get_all_multipart_uploads() method.

Comment: Thank you.  I do understand the issue with abandoned multipart uploads, and I understand what you are attempting to do with `get_all_multipart_uploads()`.  What isn't clear is the specific nature of the *current problem* you are having.  Is `get_all_multipart_uploads()` returning *some but not all* of the expected response, or nothing at all, or an error, or exactly what?  Note also that the [underlying API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadListMPUpload.html) will never return more than 1000 in-progress multipart uploads in a single response.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yeah you said it. `get_all_multipart_uploads() returning some but not all of the expected response`. So I am not able to perform the mp.cancel_upload() since I am not able to match my video against the list of videos returned

Comment: Is it returning 1000 results?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yeah I just realized I am getting 1000 records on one shot.